# Windows Script Host - Error '800A01B6' Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: c++, vbscript, com, atl, wsh

I am having an strange error with my C++ Windows API wrapper dll. I have already exposed six methods to COM with this dll. Every function works when I use them individually, but when I use COM exposed methods in VBScript like:

```
Dim AutoItX3: Set AutoItX3 = WScript.CreateObject("AutoItX3.Control")
Dim WINAPI: Set WINAPI = WScript.CreateObject("WinAPIWrapperLib.WINAPI")

WINAPI.WinAPI_EnumWindows 0

WINAPI.WinAPI_ShowWindow CLng("&h" + Replace(AutoItX3.WinGetHandle("[CLASS:Notepad]"), "0x", "")), 1
```

`EnumWindows` works fine, but when WSH comes to line of `ShowWindow`, it says:

> Error 800A01B6: Object doesn't support this property or method 'WinAPI_ShowWindow`.

But why such happens?? This object supports this method and nicely implemented.

When I only use `ShowWindow` like:

```
Dim AutoItX3: Set AutoItX3 = WScript.CreateObject("AutoItX3.Control")
Dim WINAPI: Set WINAPI = WScript.CreateObject("WinAPIWrapperLib.WINAPI")

WINAPI.WinAPI_ShowWindow CLng("&h" + Replace(AutoItX3.WinGetHandle("[CLASS:Notepad]"), "0x", "")), 1
```

It works without any problem. This error can be reproduced very easily by using those two functions like above.

How I implemented COM class:

```
coclass WinAPI
{
    [default] interface IWinAPI;
    [default, source] dispinterface _IWinAPIEvents;
};
```

My system that is running above script is Windows 7 64-bit, and dll is compiled only targeting 64-bit platforms for WSH's compatibility.

**UPDATE**

This error also happens when I use same function twice like shown below:

```
Dim WINAPI: Set WINAPI = WScript.CreateObject("WinAPIWrapperLib.WINAPI")

WINAPI.WinAPI_EnumWindows 0
WINAPI.WinAPI_EnumWindows 0
```

When it comes to executing second line, it says:

> Error 800A01B6: Object doesn't support this property or method 'WinAPI_EnumWindows`.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error by clearing a `BSTR` variable which is used by `EnumWindowsProc` callback function like this:

```
BSTR WindowClassName; //<< DECLARATION >>

RealGetWindowClass(hWnd, WindowClassName, 8192); // << USAGE IN EnumWindowsProc >>

STDMETHODIMP CWinAPI::WinAPI_EnumWindows(int lParam)
{   
    SysFreeString(WindowClassName); // << CLEARING >>

    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, lParam);

    SysFreeString(WindowClassName); // << CLEARING >>

    return S_OK;
}
```